# \mathbb symbol in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to use a $\mathbb{C}$ symbol in one of the axes in enhanced postscript in gnuplot.

This [link](https://web.lemoyne.edu/courseinformation/PHY%20333/gnuplot/docs/psdoc/ps_fontfile_doc.pdf) has a list of latex symbols that can be used in gnuplot, but it doesn't include mathbb. Is there a way to make this happen? I am aware that it can be done in the latex terminal, but I require the final image files to be in eps format.

Comment: you (I think) could use latex terminal then process the latex with latex (not pdflatex) and dvips -E to end up with an EPS file.